# Strange php malfunction setting cookies

Tags: php, cookies

So i managed to create a cookie and works perfectly in 3 different browsers under my windows 10 computer, it works perfectly also in safari and chrome under mac, but 2 friends of mine cant manage to get the cookie written under their explorers on windows 7.

Does the operating system affect to the way the cookie is written?

Heres the code:

```
flush();
header("Location:http://www.go2battle.net/prueba.php");
setcookie("go2battle", $_POST['Usuario'], time()+31556926, "/", "www.go2battle.net");
exit();
```

And i write the cookie in the prueba.php with var_dump:

```
var_dump($_COOKIE['go2battle']);
```

For me works perfectly in every single scenario i tested it, let me know if theres something wrong or some compatibility issue with operating systems that are making my windows 7 friends to fail writting the cookie, for them the return is NULL.

Thank you.

Comment: may be cookies are diabled on the browser preference.

Comment: They do have the cookies enabled as they can use them in other websites.

Answer (score 0):

`flush()` tells PHP to immediately output/print any buffered content, which means that you can no longer send headers, and cookies are set via the `Set-Cookie` header.

This *should* mean that you shouldn't be getting a cookie (nor a redirect) with that code either, but I suppose your question implies that your friends are actually running the code on their own machines as opposed to just accessing a URL provided by you.
That could explain the paradox, as it is possible that the output in question are PHP `E_WARNING`, `E_NOTICE`, etc. messages and you have those disabled while your friends don't and therefore you have output to print and they don't.

That last paragraph is just a guess though, it is also possible that `flush()` effectively "disallows" sending of headers afterwards, in which case you probably just have *previously* set that cookie set in another way.

Comment: you can test it by yourself in http://www.go2battle.net with this credentials:
Username: Loney
Password: 13571514

i removed the flush() instruction cause theres no real need for it in the code.
Every single test i run i delete every single cookie so i cant have the cookie saved.

Comment: The form for loggin in is in the top right of the website as it is in spanish so u may not understand it :S